# General CoreData Performance

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, nsfetchrequest, fetching-strategy

i have a more or less general question about using coredata the most efficient way.

i have attempted two different approaches of managing data that is shown in a view of my project.

**Approach 1**: when the view gets loaded i perform all coredata fetches and store the results in an array, the view then retrieves the displayed objects from the array. (ie: objectAtIndex:...)

**Approach 2**: the viewcontroller itself lets my data handling class perform fetches on the go, whenever a specific coredata object is needed it gets fetched.

on my current project this involes about 200-500 objects that need to be sorted and displayed in a tableview according to their attributes.

the fetch methods are the same wether i load all objects first or when i load them in batches (of correct attributes).

the difference is mainly in the cellForRow method where i have to decide if i want to pick the objects out of an array or directly from coredata.

both methods work just fine, i dont really see any performance differences just now, but i fear that with scaling of the project & more data one or the other way might be slower.

what do you think is the better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With larger data sets there may be an advantage in terms of peak memory footprint to using `NSFetchedResultsController` controller that is, presumably optimized to fetch just the right amount of data from the persistent store based on the table size.

With `NSFetchedResultsController` you have control over the fetch batch size which you can tune for performance based on the size and number of the managed objects being fetched, etc.

Comment: hi - thanks for the hint =) ive done some research on fetchtedresultscontrollers for the last hour and this looks like a great solution =)

will it cause any problems that my data is displayed in a grouped tableview? currently i represent the data with an array of arrays, for the section relevant data.

Comment: `NSFetchedResultsController` is well-suited for displaying grouped data by setting its `sectionNameKeyPath` property.